# Написать обобщённый класс называемую пирамидой (или кучей) c#

Tags: классы, структуры

Доброго времени суток, помогите пожалуйста решить эту задачу :

> Написать обобщённый класс называемую пирамидой (или кучей), хранящую
>   элементы произвольного ссылочного типа. Элементы организованы в виде
>   бинарного дерева, но хранятся в массиве раз- мера 2^h − 1, где h —
>   высота дерева (должна задаваться в конструкторе).
>    Изначально элементы массива равны нулевой ссылке и считаются пустыми. 
>    Элементы добавляются так же, как и в бинарном дереве поиска.
>   Класс должен содержать методы: Add — добавить элемент с указанным
>   значением в пирамиду, •Exist — проверить, содержит ли пирамида элемент с
>   указанным значением.

Как вообще задать размер ? тут есть пример : https://habrahabr.ru/post/112222/ но там размер другой и я не особо понял, как и где он задается. Можете помочь ?

Comment: кстати `проверить, содержит ли пирамида элемент с указанным значением` это совсем не стандартная операция кучи. Настолько нестандартная что я бы отдельный `map` ради неё завёл. И кстати а зачем куча если все операции - добавить и проверить есть ли элемент. Это `set`...

Answer (score 1):

В статье куча динамического размера. От вас же просят сделать дерево поверх массива. В каком-то смысле, это есть велосипед - вам придется сначала поверх массива написать свой менеджер памяти (фактически, реализовать std::vector из C++), а потом, используя этот менеджер, сделать дерево.

Comment: а есть какой-то пример иль чтот подобное ? ибо я не оч представляю себе, как это реализовать :(

Comment: Я бы сказал что вектор тут не нужен,  достаточно поддерживать количество элементов/указатель на последний.

Comment: @pavel, а что, для реализации std::vector нужно хранить что-то еще? Что именно?

Comment: @gbg я думал что для реализации вектора нужно память перевыделять уменьшать и так далее. Здесь же всё значительно проще.

Comment: @pavel тут задача конкретно поставлена - максимальный размер дан свыше. Наиболее близкий контейнер, подходящий под это дело - вектор, которому сразу после создания сделали .reserve()

Но я сомневаюсь, что нашему стюденту дадут использовать STL, поэтому, ему придется велосипедить свой вектор, хотя бы частично.

Comment: @gbg а вас вообще не смущают операции и почему это кучей названо? Чистейший `set` же...

Comment: @pavel - ну, тут очевидно, что просят навелосипедить set, но поверх массива. сам set можно реализовать разными способами - хорошим (поверх дерева), плохим (поверх массива, который поддерживается сортированным, вставка линейна, поиск за логарифм) и уродским (просто поверх массива, с линейной сложностью поиска и вставки).

Comment: огромное спасибо вам за комментарии и за помощь, но все же, можете подкинуть литры или примеров каких, как эт вообще сделать ?

Comment: @Lolidze язык-то какой?

Comment: C# (он самый::)

Comment: @gbg мало кто умеет писать правильно дерево, так чтобы на тесте `1 2 3 .. N` оно в цепочку не выродилось. Если бы мне поставили задачу писать БЕЗ стандартный алгоритмов, то только хеш-таблица...

Comment: @Lolidze а как вы себе представляете это для любого типа? Как минимум надо чтобы операция сравнения была определена.

Comment: @Lolidze http://e-maxx.ru/algo/treap вот самое подходящее по вашему вопросу. Если в литературу просите.

Comment: там вродь  как на c++ , сильно отличаться будет от c# ?